# How to draw this figure with arrows

Tags: diagrams

How can I draw the following figure [image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Could you show what you've tried so far and what exactly you're struggling with?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. frankly speaking, I am a layman to draw figs in latex. Please help me to plot the figure in latex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the following is one way to do it. It's a simple *draw from a to b* solution with a *bend* on each line. You also could draw these lines via the `(x1, y1) .. controls (x,y) .. (x2,y2)` method or even try to plot them as mathematical functions.

The way you do it in the end is open to you. The following code is an example on how to set the arrowheads on different parts of the lines. You can fit this to your preferred way of creating the lines.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows}

\tikzset{
    base/.style={
        draw, 
        very thick, 
        postaction={decorate},
    },
    single/.style={
        base,
        decoration={markings, mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{triangle 45}}},
    },
    double/.style={
        base,
       decoration={markings, mark=at position .25 with {\arrow{triangle 45}}},
       decoration={markings, mark=at position .75 with {\arrow{triangle 45}}},
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [single] (0,0) to [bend left=20] ++(2,-2);
    \draw [double] (.5,.5) to [bend left=25] ++(2,-2);
    \draw [single] (1,1) to [bend left=20] ++(.75,-1.25);
    \draw [single] (3,1) to [] ++(-1.25,-1.25);
    \draw [single] (2.5,1) to [bend right=10] ++(-.75,-1.25);
    \draw [single] (3.5,.5) to [bend left=10] ++(-1.75,-.75);
    \draw [single] (3.5,0) to [bend right=50] ++(-.5,-1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The code produces:

[image: output of code example]

Comment: \begin{figure}
  \centering   
  \begin{overpic}[width=9cm,height=5cm]{abc.eps}
     \put(5,5){\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [single] (0,0) to [bend left=20] ++(2,-2);
    \draw [double] (.5,.5) to [bend left=25] ++(2,-2);
    \draw [single] (1,1) to [bend left=20] ++(.75,-1.25);
    \draw [single] (3,1) to [] ++(-1.25,-1.25);
    \draw [single] (2.5,1) to [bend right=10] ++(-.75,-1.25);
    \draw [single] (3.5,.5) to [bend left=10] ++(-1.75,-.75);
    \draw [single] (3.5,0) to [bend right=50] ++(-.5,-1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}}

Comment: I want plot this fig to another eps and I want to resize this overlaying fig so that it will adjust with the size of the esp.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean with "*I want to resize this overlaying fig so that it will adjust with the size of the esp*", but you can adjust the size of a graphic to the textwidth by wrapping in `\resizebox{!}{\textwidth}{...}`.

Comment: If you want to resize the *tikz*-figure you can use the *xscale* and *yscale*. Example: `\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.5, yscale=2] ... \end{tikzpicture}`. Is this what you mean?